# Error installing resource from QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, proxy

I have installed the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin in QGIS.

When I try to install the Mapbox's Maki Icons resource or OpenStreetMap style resource I get the following error message:

> Error: urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired

My network options in QGIS are currently set to Use proxy for web access with DefaultProxy set as the Proxy type.

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug report on the plugin's bug tracker https://github.com/akbargumbira/qgis_resources_sharing/issues rather than a GIS.SE question.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem persist with a more recent version of QGIS and the *QGIS Resource Sharing* plugin? Version 0.15.1 of the plugin was released May 28 '20.